# simplexml_load_file not working with variable but works with string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to connect to a CRM (Pardot).

I have this to create the URL necessary to call the XML:

```
//this will log in and print your API Key (good for 1 hour) to the console
$rz_key = callPardotApi('https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3', 
array(
    'email' => 'myemail@email.com',
    'password' => 'password',
    'user_key' => '032222222222222b75a192daba28d' 
)
 );

$number_url  = 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/query';
$number_url .= '?user_key=032222222222222b75a192daba28d';
$number_url .= '&api_key=';
$number_url .= trim($rz_key);
$number_url .= '&list_id=97676';

$ike = simplexml_load_file($number_url);
print_r($ike);
```

Now this code returns :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [stat] => fail [version] => 1.0 )   [err] => Invalid API key or user key )
```

However, if I echo `$number_url`, and copy and paste that URL into my browser, it loads wonderfully. If I copy and paste the same echoed URL into `simplexml_load_file` it works wonderfully also. I MUST use a variable, because the API key is only good for one hour. Any ideas?

The rest of the code is here, which was provided by Pardot :

```
<?php
/**
 * Call the Pardot API and get the raw XML response back
 * 
 * @param string $url the full Pardot API URL to call, e.g. "https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/query"
 * @param array $data the data to send to the API - make sure to include your api_key and user_key for authentication
 * @param string $method GET", "POST", "DELETE"
 * @return string the raw XML response from the Pardot API
 * @throws Exception if we were unable to contact the Pardot API or something went wrong
 */
function callPardotApi($url, $data, $method = 'GET')
{
// build out the full url, with the query string attached.
$queryString = http_build_query($data, null, '&');
if (strpos($url, '?') !== false) {
    $url = $url . '&' . $queryString;
} else {
    $url = $url . '?' . $queryString;
}

$curl_handle = curl_init($url);

// wait 5 seconds to connect to the Pardot API, and 30
// total seconds for everything to complete
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

// https only, please!
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);

// ALWAYS verify SSL - this should NEVER be changed. 2 = strict verify
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

// return the result from the server as the return value of curl_exec instead of echoing it
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

if (strcasecmp($method, 'POST') === 0) {
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
} elseif (strcasecmp($method, 'GET') !== 0) {
    // perhaps a DELETE?
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, strtoupper($method));
}

$pardotApiResponse = curl_exec($curl_handle);
if ($pardotApiResponse === false) {
    // failure - a timeout or other problem. depending on how you want to handle failures,
    // you may want to modify this code. Some folks might throw an exception here. Some might
    // log the error. May you want to return a value that signifies an error. The choice is yours!

    // let's see what went wrong -- first look at curl
    $humanReadableError = curl_error($curl_handle);

    // you can also get the HTTP response code
    $httpResponseCode = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // make sure to close your handle before you bug out!
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    throw new Exception("Unable to successfully complete Pardot API call to $url -- curl error: \"".
                            "$humanReadableError\", HTTP response code was:     $httpResponseCode");
}

    // make sure to close your handle before you bug out!
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    return $pardotApiResponse;
}

//this will log in and print your API Key (good for 1 hour) to the console

 $rz_key = callPardotApi('https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3', 
 array(
    'email' => 'myemail@email.com',
    'password' => 'myPassword',
    'user_key' => '********************' 
 )
);

$number_url  = 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/query';
$number_url .= '?user_key=****************';
$number_url .= '&api_key=';
$number_url .= $rz_key;
$number_url .= '&list_id=97676';

$number_url = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $number_url);

$ike = simplexml_load_file($number_url);
print_r($ike);

?>
```

Comment: I know you may have tried this but, just for the sake of trying, try using the strings used to build that variable directly to see if by any change the building of the variable is the problem? What I mean is putting simplexml_load_file('url'.'?user_key=abc'.'&api_key='.$rz_key

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This was actually resolved - It turns out that the variable $rz_key was returned as an XML file in itself - I had to use simplexml_load_file on $rz_key , and grab the value from the parsed xml. I then injected the new variable into the string and it worked!